# How to find a definition of a specific syscall in Linux sources?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

I recently wanted to see how is `open()` system call implemented in Linux kernel. Looking at the syscall table suggested that the name of the function I'm looking for is `sys_open()`, so I grepped for it. I couldn't find any declaration though, the closest I could get was `do_sys_open` in `fs/open.c`. Is it somehow translated into this function? What may I have missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `do_sys_open` is not the implementation of `sys_open`, it's just a common code of `open` and `openat` factored out.

Syscall function names, which are always `sys_`*something*, are generated by funny preprocessor macros (`SYSCALL_DEFINEn` where `n` is the number of arguments).

As you can see (very close to `do_sys_open`):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(open, const char __user *, filename, int, flags, umode_t, mode)
{
        long ret;
        ....
```

*This* is the code of `open` syscall.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! For future reference, what is the easiest way of figuring out such caveats? Was it in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: Seems not to be documented (that is, there are some explanations on the Internet, no more official than mine). Pretty easy to figure it out when you look at cross-referenced linux source: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.7.4/fs/open.c or http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=sys_open (you just need enough curiousity to look up unknown macros all the way down, and some intuition telling where to expect interesting things).